# Expects char* but is char(*) [20]

Tags: c, cgi, scanf

I'm trying to write a script to except data from GET request using sscanf. I seem to be having a problem with parsing it with sscanf and passing it on to a variable. I think that the issue is something to do with my char type, but may also have to do with my Regex string because the error gives the group as "%[a-z,A-Z" and not "%[a-z,A-Z]" like I'd expect it to. You can see the full source code at http://cs.mcgill.ca/~phwang3/cgi-bin/searchRecord.c, but I've highlighted the main stuff here.

I seem to be getting an error

```
 warning: format ‘%[a-z,A-Z’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char * (*)[20]’ [-Wformat]
```

at this line

```
if(sscanf(data,"firstName=%[a-z,A-Z]&lastName=%[a-z,A-Z]",&firstName, &lastName)!=2) {
```

the variables in question are declared before the above line as

```
char firstName[20] = {0};
char lastName[20] = {0};
```

also relevant, I suppose, is that the query is stored in the variable "data", and also declared before the poblematic string.

```
char* data;
data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(sscanf(data,"firstName=%[a-z,A-Z]&lastName=%[a-z,A-Z]",
    &firstName, &lastName)!=2) {
```

You have to pass `firstName` and `lastName` and not `&firstName` and `&lastName`.

Comment: Sweet! That worked. why is this though? Was I specifying the address rather than the pointer?

Comment: even better would be `&firstName[0]` and `&lastName[0]`

Comment: @JosephSzymborski You have to pass a pointer to `char` but you passed a pointer to the array.

Comment: @D.Shawley it is matter of taste, but I prefer `firstName` which is more compact.